# SMT32 Timer PWM output only works in debug mode

Tags: debugging, stm32, iar, adc, pwm

I generated code for the stm32f105 processor using stm32cube. This one is using adc, uart and timer with pwm output.

When running the code in debug mode everything works normally. But when removing debug mode, the pwm output does not change.

I am using IAR for ARM 8.22.1

I am not using HAL_Delay. I already changed the priority of SysTick. Changed clock frequency. Changed the linker.

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_WWDG_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();

  Sys_ResetVar();
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3,TIM_CHANNEL_1);

  while (1)
  {
    Sys_ModeControl();
    Sys_RefreshScreen();
    Sys_CommControl(); 
    HAL_WWDG_Refresh(&hwwdg);
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.Prediv1Source = RCC_PREDIV1_SOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLL2State = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCPCLK2_DIV6;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/50);
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);
  __HAL_RCC_PLLI2S_ENABLE();
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_239CYCLES_5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}

static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 32;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 20;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_TRIGGER;
  sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR0;
  if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sSlaveConfig) !=     HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC1REF;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 20;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_LOW;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);

}

static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_2;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}

static void MX_WWDG_Init(void)
{
  hwwdg.Instance = WWDG;
  hwwdg.Init.Prescaler = WWDG_PRESCALER_8;
  hwwdg.Init.Window = 0x7F;
  hwwdg.Init.Counter = 0x7F;
  hwwdg.Init.EWIMode = WWDG_EWI_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_WWDG_Init(&hwwdg) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_0 
                      |GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_5 
                      |uC_DATA_INA_Pin|uC_CLKA_Pin|uC_LEA_Pin|GPIO_PIN_10 
                      |GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4 
                      |GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|RS485_ENA_Pin 
                      |GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,     CTRL_ROWA1_Pin|CTRL_ROWA2_Pin|CTRL_ROWA3_Pin|CTRL_ROWA11_Pin 
                         |CTRL_ROWA12_Pin|CTRL_ROWA13_Pin|CTRL_ROWA14_Pin|CTRL_ROWA15_Pin 
                          |CTRL_ROWA16_Pin|CTRL_ROWA4_Pin|CTRL_ROWA5_Pin|CTRL_ROWA6_Pin 
                          |CTRL_ROWA7_Pin|CTRL_ROWA8_Pin|CTRL_ROWA9_Pin|CTRL_ROWA10_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_0 
                      |GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_5 
                      |uC_DATA_INA_Pin|uC_CLKA_Pin|uC_LEA_Pin|GPIO_PIN_10 
                      |GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4 
                      |GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|RS485_ENA_Pin 
                      |GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CTRL_ROWA1_Pin|CTRL_ROWA2_Pin|CTRL_ROWA3_Pin|CTRL_ROWA11_Pin 
                      |CTRL_ROWA12_Pin|CTRL_ROWA13_Pin|CTRL_ROWA14_Pin|CTRL_ROWA15_Pin 
                      |CTRL_ROWA16_Pin|CTRL_ROWA4_Pin|CTRL_ROWA5_Pin|CTRL_ROWA6_Pin 
                      |CTRL_ROWA7_Pin|CTRL_ROWA8_Pin|CTRL_ROWA9_Pin|CTRL_ROWA10_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
```

The code should read adc and generate a pwm according to the value read. The other features of UART work normally. The only thing that doesn't work is pwm.

Comment: 1) What does *removing debug mode* mean? Changing compiler settings (which ones?), or disconnecting the debug probe? 2) Please provide a [mcve]. Obviously missing are the code to enable peripherals (except GPIO), set alternate functions to pins, change PWM duty cycle. 3) Verify that all fields in every structure are initialized. Local variables can have unpredictable values, it's possible that they are initialized to `0` in a debug environment, but have some other value in a release build. 4) What are the timer master and slave configurations supposed to do? Remove them if you don't use them.

Comment: This looks like a watchdog issue. IAR disables the watchdog when entering debug mode. To test this just comment the `MX_WWDG_Init();` and `HAL_WWDG_Refresh(&hwwdg);` and test without debugging.